# Call method in UIViewController from didSelectRowAtIndexPath in NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I have a UIViewController(A) that uses an NSObject with delegate methods  to display a UITableView programmatically. This works great.

But then when I select a row I want to load a different UIViewController(B). I have tried to use a NSNotification on UIViewController(A) that is called in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. However this takes about 20 seconds to load the UIViewController(B).

NOTE: I know there is nothing wrong with UIViewController(B) in terms of loading.

I have checked that the displaying of UIViewController(B) is on the main thread. Which it is.

I am therefore thinking that there may be an alternative method to display UIViewController(B). The alternative method I am thinking is to write a method in UIViewController(A) to present UIViewController(B). But how can I call this from the NSObject didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it to work. So for anyone who is having the same troubles. My answer came from https://github.com/burczyk/KBContactsSelection